# Understanding of an assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86

```
...
MOV ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[__argc_dll]
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x8]
MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX], ECX
MOV ECX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0xC]
MOV EDX, DWORD PTR DS:[__argv_dll]
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EBP+0x10]
POP EBP
...
```

So i have written the following code (in C):

```
int ecx = 0;
ecx = 1;       //because the value in [__argc_dll] was 00000001

int *func1 = &00404020;         //because [EBP+0x8]=00404020

int *eax = *func1;              // is the assembly line MOV EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x8]
eax = ecx;                      // is the assembly line MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EAX], ECX


type *func2 = &00404024;       // because [EBP+0xC]=00404024
type *ecx   = &func2;          //  MOV ECX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0xC]

type *edx   = &argv_dll        //is the assembly lineMOV EDX, DWORD PTR DS:[__argv_dll]


type *func3 = &00404028;       // because [EBP+0x10]=00404028
type *eax = &func3;            //the line: MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[EBP+0x10]
```

So my questions would be:
Is that a correct representation? I must admit that I am newbie with regard to the pointer-concept.
So what I did was : 
I assume that the 3 values on the stack addresses [EBP+0x8], [EBP+0xC] and [EBP+0x10] are normal addresses and create at first 3 pointer to them. 
And after I create other pointers like *eax which also point to that addresses.

My 2nd question would be:
How can I implement a pop operation like **POP EBP** at the end of my assembly code? Do i need it really for the representation ? I would say no, or ?

Ollydbg shows at that line that EBP is at

```
Stack [EBP]=[0012FF40]=0012FF88
EBP = 0012FF40
```

After that operation I have EBP = 0012FF88.

Comment: EBP is used for marking a stack frame. That means, upon entry to a function, it is set such that it points to the arguments, passed to the function. the arguments are pushed to stack (ESP), and the return address is pushed on top of those.  pointing EBP to those arguments makes it easier to access them - and that explains what   there is to be found on those [EBP+offset] addresses: the arguments the function was called with.

Comment: you don't really need to pop from EBP. just read values from there. At the end of the function, the stack frame will be destroyed, which means, ESP corrected such that former EBP contents are now in memory free for reuse.

Comment: if you coded that function, and need to clean up stack at the end, do this:    mov esp,ebp  ;   set stack pointer to where previous ebp was stacked      pop ebp  ; restore ebp, and clean up stack

Comment: ok, and what would you say about the written C-code which should represent the given assembly? Is that ok? Acceptable ? Or Not so good?

Comment: I don't think that representing that code in C makes an awful amount of sense, for several reasons: were you to run the code, it wouldn't do what you hope for. if it is for understanding what it does, it also doesn't help. Why is that?  Because: 1. you code hard values of a dynamic nature. You try to represent code in a language whose compiler  generates such code as part of its own function. You use memory locations or unspecified registers where use of specific register is required

Comment: For understanding that section of code, I assert that studying and understanding the code in its assembly representation is more productive than attempting a non-equivalent representation in a different language.

Comment: I coded it only to have a rough version of it in C code. Not a detailed version. It was also a little challenge to understand the pointer concept better.

Comment: I'm afraid you C representation doesn't help with that. For example., in your code you asume that the arguments passed to function are pointers to code - how do you know? were you to pass literal data, you'd simply read the data from [ebx+offset] location. Actually, that's what the assembly code does, as witnessed in MOV EAX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+0x8], where one passed argument is merely copied to EAX register

Comment: I understand it but it does not help me with that question.